# How to search within nested objects

Tags: vue.js, algolia

I have done my research trying to figure out how to achieve what I am describing below, however I had no luck.

In my Algolia index, some records have nested objects.
For example, `title` and `subtitle` attributes are of the following format:

```
title:
{ 
   "en": "English title", 
   "gr": "Greek title" 
}
```

I would like to execute queries only for a specific subset (in our example "en" or "gr") of these attributes, withoute "exposing" any facet in the UI — language selection would ideally be done “automatically” based on a variable (`lang`) passed to the Vue component with props. I am using **Laravel Scout** package with default **Vue** implementation, as described in documentation [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/framework-integration/laravel/tutorials/getting-started-with-laravel-scout-vuejs/).

My InstantSearch implementation is pretty simple, I am not defining anything specific regarding queries and searchable attributes, I am currently using all the default functionality of Algolia.

```
<template>
    <ais-instant-search
            :search-client="searchClient"
            index-name="posts_index"
    >
        <div class="search-box">
            <ais-search-box placeholder="Search posts..."></ais-search-box>
        </div>
        <ais-hits>
            <template
                slot="item"
                slot-scope="{ item }"
            >
                <div class="list-image">
                    <img :src="'/images/' + item.image" />
                </div>
                <div class="list-text">
                    <h2">
                         {{ item.title }}
                    </h2>
                    <h3>
                        {{ item.subtitle }}
                    </h3>
                </div>

            </template>
        </ais-hits>
    </ais-instant-search>
</template>

<script>
    import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                searchClient: algoliasearch(
                    process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
                    process.env.ALGOLIA_SEARCH
                ),
                route: route,
            };
        },
        props: ['lang'],
        computed: {
            computedItem() {
                // computed_item = this.item;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

I would like to somehow pass an option to query “title.en” and “subtitle.en” when variable `lang` is set to “en”. All this, without the user having to select “title.en” or “subtitle.en” in the UI.

### Update

Maybe **computed properties** is the path to go, however I cannot find how to reference search results/hits attributes (eg `item.title`) within computed property. It is the code I have commented out.

Comment: Where is the variable *language* coming from ? You said cookies but I cant see it in the code

Comment: @onuriltan I just edited my original post to include lang variable, passed as props to the vue component.

Comment: Can you review the answer? I can help if it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use computed property. Just transform current item according to the current language variable.

```js
new Vue({
  template: "<div>{{ computedItem.title }}</div>",
  data: {
    langFromCookie: "en",
    item: {
      title: {
        en: "Hello",
        ru: "Привет"
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedItem() {
      const item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.item));

      for (value in item) {
        if (typeof item[value] === "object" && Object.keys(item[value]).includes(this.langFromCookie))
          item[value] = item[value][this.langFromCookie];
      }

      return item;
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app")
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like the approach, but your solution only transforms the records (results) being displayed after searching, rather than modifying the search query to limit the results? Do I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

If lang variable is available via props, you can check that inside **list-text class** and return {{title.en}} or {{title.gr}} accordingly by passing a dynamic lang value **title[lang]** like below

```html
...

<div class="list-text">
   <h2>
      {{ item.title[lang] }}
   </h2>
   <h3>
      {{ item.subtitle[lang] }}
   </h3>
</div>
```

If you want to make a request according to lang prop when component mounts ,then you can **make a request inside mounted()** method then query like below

```js
mounted() {
  axios.get(`/getSomethingWithLang/:${this.item.title[this.lang]}`)
  ... 
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this only affects the way the results (eg. item.title) are being displayed and not how they are queried. I would like to query item.title[lang], not only display item.title[lang]

Comment: When do you want to query? After **lang prop** change? Query you mean api request to some endpoint?

Comment: lang prop does not change, however I want to query (or "search") in "title.en", for example, when the lang is "en". Not just displaying "title.en". I think that I have to find a way to reference "item" within computed property, because there is no "item"  within data().

Comment: So you want to do it on component mount, if lang is "en" then you want to query, if lang is "gr" than you want to query as well but with different lang parameters as far as I understand

Comment: Right, if lang is "en" I want to query title.en, if lang is "gr" I want to query title.gr.

Comment: I don't want to make extra requests or modify the way Algolia's InstantSearch is "automatically" working. I have included InstantSearch's Vue component which takes care of the searching/querying functionality and I am wondering if there is a way to modify this a little bit, in order to include the 'lang' property, not implement the whole querying all over... Thank you very much for your effort, though.